# Password reset function in django admin is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.urls import re_path
from App.views import *
from.router import router
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import ( TokenObtainPairView,TokenRefreshView)
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="social_app/index.html")), #social_app/index.html
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),         #admin api
    path('api/',include(router.urls)),          #api
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),       #allauth
    re_path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),    #rest_auth
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    re_path('/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api/token/', MyObtainTokenPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('jobview/',job),
    path('timelog/',timelogview),
    path('chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    path('admin/password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),name='admin_password_reset',),
    path('admin/password_reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),name='password_reset_done',),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),name='password_reset_confirm',),
    path('reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),name='password_reset_complete',),
    
    

]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I have given the password reset function in the admin page login, it is showing as "Forgotten your password or username?" in the page but when I click it the url changes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/password_reset/` to this but the same login page is loading i didnt redirected to any other reset page.

I have tried but couldn't able to fix it, kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: `admin.site.urls` includes a final catch all url pattern which is catching your urls. Your urls with an `admin/` prefix should be before the admin sites urls or should have a different prefix.

Comment: hey thanks it works fine now after giving it before admin sites urls. But while clicking the link in the email to reset password it is showing as example.com and no reset password page arrives. Do i need to change it in the respective html file?

Comment: Why would you put `example.com` in your HTML file? Obviously that is an example from wherever you copied it... You could replace it with `{{ request.get_host }}` in your template (Note: The request must be in the context to do this) to get the current domain.

Comment: {% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}

it is what declared in the email sending in the domain whether i need to mention the {{ request.get_host }} or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add all urls with ***`admin`*** before ***`path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`***
2. Then add this line of code in your ***`admin.py`*** file and run the server and connect with your admin account then go to Site model and edit domain ***example.com*** with ***`http://127.0.0.1:8000`*** when you're in development (in production it will be your server link)  and edit name ***example.com*** with whatever name you want for your site.

   ```
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
    from django.contrib import admin

    @admin.register(Site)
    class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('domain', 'name')
    search_fields = ('domain', 'name')
   ```